# How to retrieve RichTextBox content with the controls inside of it(buttons)?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I am facing a challange using RichTextBox control:

I am successfully able to add paragraphs to it and buttons in design time just fine, see xaml below:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtxtStep" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="207" Margin="10,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="427" IsDocumentEnabled="True" KeyUp="richTextBox_KeyUp">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Section FontSize="15">
                    <Paragraph>
                        Click on this:

                            <Hyperlin k  NavigateUri="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</Hyperlin k>


                    </Paragraph>

                    <Paragraph>
                        <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="143" >Also Click On This</Button>
                        <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="143" >button 2</Button>
                    </Paragraph>
                </Section>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
```

and I am able to retrieve the text from my code just fine, see below:

```
    private void richTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            TextRange txtrContent = new TextRange(rtxtStep.Document.ContentStart, rtxtStep.Document.ContentEnd);
            string allContent = txtrContent.Text;
        }
    }
```

returning:

```
"Click on this: stackoverflow\r\n   \r\n\r\n"
```

the question is, How Do I retrieve the buttons as well as the text?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are really expecting too much.  The FlowDocument in the RichTextBox is a hierarchy of elements.  The best you can do is to descend the tree of elements to find the buttons.  Something like this...

```
    private void richTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            TextRange txtrContent = new TextRange(rtxtStep.Document.ContentStart, rtxtStep.Document.ContentEnd);
            string allContent = txtrContent.Text;
            PrintBlocks(rtxtStep.Document.Blocks);
        }
    }

    private void PrintBlocks(IEnumerable<Block> blocks)
    {
        foreach(Block b in blocks)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Found " + b.GetType().Name);
            if(b is Section)
            {
                PrintBlocks((b as Section).Blocks);
            }
            else if(b is Paragraph)
            {
                PrintInlines((b as Paragraph).Inlines);
            }
        }

    }

    private void PrintInlines(IEnumerable<Inline> inlines)
    {
        foreach(Inline i in inlines)
        {
            if(i is InlineUIContainer)
            {
                PrintInlineUIContainer(i as InlineUIContainer);
            }

        }
    }
    private void PrintInlineUIContainer(InlineUIContainer i)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Found " + i.Child.GetType().Name + " " + i.Child.ToString());
    }
```

For your XAML, this output is generated...

```
Found Section
Found Paragraph 
Found Paragraph
Found Button System.Windows.Controls.Button: Also Click On This
Found Button System.Windows.Controls.Button: button 2
```

But you knew this already.  You seem to want the text and buttons in some integrated format (perhaps HTML?).  I think you would need to write your own code to do this.